# embedding short python scripts as an alias for Bash

Tags: python, bash

In my.bash rc file, I want to assign quick Python scripts to a bash alias. Is there a way to do it without using zsh's join?

Comment: Save your sanity, use functions instead of aliases. Among other things, aliases go through an extra level of quote/escape processing and removal, which makes embedding a Python script (with *its* quotes and escapes) in shell quotes/escapes extra complicated.

Comment: `Using bash alias without using zsh's join` reads like you are confusing  apples and bananas. Bash and Zsh are both shell scripting language with their own specificities.

Comment: @LéaGris I agree, but solved something using that before. So, mentioning that I don't want that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, here is how:

```
   myscript() {
    python -c "print('Hello, world!')"
}
```

Comment: That won't work, because escaping doesn't work inside single-quoted strings. You'd have to use something like `alias myscript='python -c "print('\''Hello, world!'\'')"'`. A function would be simpler: `myscript() { python -c "print('Hello, world!')"; }`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just edited my answer. Is that correct ?